# Yii2 Роутинг модуля

Tags: php, yii2, api, модули

Пишу api модуль на yii2, и использую для версионирования субмодули. И проблема в том, что не могу получить доступ к странице в суб модуле, просто получаю 404.
Вот так я описал его в config:

```
'modules' => [
    'api' => [
        'basePath' => '@app/api',
        'class' => app\api\ApiModule::class,
        'modules' => [
            'v1' => [
                'basePath' => '@app/api/v1',
                'class' => app\api\v1\V1Module::class,
            ]
        ],
        'components' => [
            'request' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\Request',
                'parsers' => [
                    'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
                ],
                'enableCsrfValidation' => false,
                'enableCsrfCookie' => false,
            ],
            'response' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\Response',
                'formatters' => [
                    \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON => [
                        'class' => 'yii\web\JsonResponseFormatter',
                        'prettyPrint' => YII_DEBUG,
                        'encodeOptions' => JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
],
...
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'enableStrictParsing' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => ['api/v1/user']],

            '/' => 'site/index',
        ],
    ],
```

Нужна ваша помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем-то я так и не понял в чём проблема, но теперь всё работает, а настройка выглядит так:

```
web.php
'modules' => [
    'api' => [
        'basePath' => '@api',
        'class' => 'app\api\ApiModule',
        'modules' => [
            'v1' => [
                'basePath' => '@api/v1',
                'class' => 'app\api\v1\V1Module',
            ]
        ],
        'components' => $config_api
    ]
],
...
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'enableStrictParsing' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => ['api/v1/user'],
            'patterns' => [
                'PUT,PATCH {id}' => 'update',
                'DELETE {id}' => 'delete',
                'GET,HEAD {id}' => 'view',
                'POST' => 'create',
                'GET,HEAD' => 'index',
                '{id}' => 'options',
                '' => 'options',
                'OPTIONS <id:\d+>/<action:[\w-]+>' => 'options',
                'OPTIONS <action:[\w-]+>' => 'options',
                '<id:\d+>/<action:[\w-]+>' => '<action>',
                '<action:[\w-]+>' => '<action>'
            ]
        ],

        '/' => 'site/index',
    ]
]
```